# Apache 2.4.37 reload causes error "scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit."

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm running CentOS 8 with Apache 2.4.37.

Once per day, logrotate rotates the Apache logs by doing a graceful restart (reload):

```
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1413:tid 140292271810880] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1413:tid 140292271810880] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1413:tid 140292271810880] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1g configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 1413:tid 140292271810880] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Immediately after this reload, I see the following errors filling my Apache error log:

```
[mpm_event:error] [pid 1413:tid 140292271810880] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
```

The server then becomes unresponsive, and it continues logging the above error and will not begin working again until I manually restart the Apache process.

I assume that there are some processes that take time to finish, and that the server runs out of worker processes during the reload operation. For some reason, this causes it to hang and be unable to recover by itself. However, the Apache logs do get rotated, so I believe at least part of the reload operation was successful.

I have not tried making any adjustments to the MPM Event config settings -- mostly because I'm not sure what setting for ServerLimit would be "correct," and any guess would be a shot in the dark.

Can anyone suggest what might fix this issue, given that it seems to happen only during a graceful reload?

Is there some other way I can avoid the server hanging, or is it simply necessary to increase the ServerLimit as the error suggests?

My research on this issue brings up a lot of results about an old Apache bug related to MPM Event mode, but my version of Apache shouldn't be affected by this particular bug.

Thank you very much for any guidance.

Comment: I have the same problem and found your question here. Maybe this blog post helps: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/948/apache-2.4-mpm-event-bug-freezing-up-scoreboard-full-after-reload

Comment: Thank you. I've just posted my own solution, in case that helps you. The Apache mailing list was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

After not getting any replies here, I brought up this issue on the Apache users mailing list. They suggested increasing some limits for the Event MPM. I'm now using the following settings, and the issue hasn't occurred again:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
   ServerLimit 48
   ThreadsPerChild 25
   MaxRequestWorkers 800
</IfModule>
```

They specifically mentioned that the `ServerLimit` should be set higher than I previously had it set (32) so that Apache would have some headroom. It wasn't clear to me from the documentation that this was needed. But it seems to have done the trick.